# End of Month difference calculation using pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement and need to fullfill  the following request:

```
IF EndOfMonth(to_date(df.col1, 'DD.MM.YYYY')) >= EOM(CURRENT_DATE):
THEN "OldCustomer"
ELSE "NewCustomer"
```

Input dataframe:

```
col1 (stringtype)
20190523
20200428
20130819
```

Current_date: getting from python import datetime

```
from datetime import date

now = date.today()
```

Output Should be like:

```
col1 (Stringtype)  col1_formated  customer(stringtype)
 20190523          23.05.2019     oldcustomer
 20200428          28.04.2020     newcustomer
 20130819          19.03.2013     oldcustomer
```

Please help in the eom format coding? It would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[`last_day`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#last_day) function is what you're looking for:

```
df.withColumn("col1_formated", date_format(to_date("col1", "yyyyMMdd"), "dd.MM.yyyy")) \
  .withColumn("customer",
              when(last_day(to_date("col1", "yyyyMMdd")) >= last_day(current_date()),
                   "OldCustomer").otherwise("NewCustomer")
             ).show()
```

Comment: Hi, When i try with 
**withColumn("col1_formated", date_format(to_date("col1", "yyyyMMdd"), "dd.MM.yyyy"))** is returing StringType, but i need DateType format.
hence can i use cast() or anyother method can be allowed here ????

Comment: If you want to store it as Date type then remove `date_format` and use it when you select to format your date as `dd.MM.yyyy`.

Comment: Could you provide an example ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do this using simple [`udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf) function.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# sample data
d = [('20190523',), ('20200428',), ('20130819',)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(d, ['dates'])

# format date column
df = df.withColumn('date_format' , F.to_date('dates', 'yyyyMMdd'))

# take any date from the sample data
today = date(2020, 4, 28)

# create a udf function
func = F.udf(lambda x: 'newcustomer' if x == today else 'oldcustomer')

# apply the function
df = df.withColumn('customer', func('date_format'))

+--------+-----------+-----------+
|   dates|date_format|   customer|
+--------+-----------+-----------+
|20190523| 2019-05-23|oldcustomer|
|20200428| 2020-04-28|newcustomer|
|20130819| 2013-08-19|oldcustomer|
+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Please don't encourage using UDFs for such transformations. There are Spark builtin functions for what the OP wants to achieve.

Comment: Sure, though I often use udf since they help me visualise the code flow better. Added my approach for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Even with the udf i treid and it was working fine. The only mistake i have done in not using the **date_format**. Thanks @YOLO